# How to unbind a click listener in java script in a public webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onclicklistener

I am developing a chrome extension. In my contentScript, I want to unbind the click listener of a "div". The div is like this:

Web code of the div.

[image: Web code of the div.]

This is what it looks like.

[image: This is what it looks like.]

When I click anywhere in this div area, it will open a link. I have already knew the reason which is this div has a click listener.  How could I unbind this click listener.  I used **div.onclick = null; div.onclick = function(){}**. Those methods didn't work.

Comment: Add a listener to a parent element and use `preventDefault`

Comment: Could you give me some examples?

Comment: It works. **But no matter where I click, the link cannot be opened.**

Comment: Check event.target

Comment: I just learn js for two days. Could u give some code example? Appreciate it.